# SQL Synchronising large table data

Tags: sql-server-2008

Hi i m using SQL 2008 R2.What is the faster way to insert data of 10 mil. records from one table A into another empty table B.
Table A and B dont have same schema similar but not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only 10 million rows. Just use a normal INSERT

```
INSERT tableB (col1, col2, col3, ...)
SELECT col1, col2, col3, ... FROM tableA
```

or

```
--assumes no table b already
SELECT col1, col2, col3, ..., INTO TableB FROM tableA
.. now add some columns etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Your using sql?

why not create a new table 
and then insert records from table a into new table b??

Comment: How much time do i need for that aporoach to synchronize?